# Really weird "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in _ on line 4"

Tags: php

So what I've found out is that usually this error is caused because line before this line didn't end with ;, but I've tried to go through the code multiple times but I didn't find the missing semicolon.

```
<?php
$json_array = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/superihippo'), true);
if ($json_array['stream'] != NULL) {
    $channelTitle = $json_array['stream']['channel']['display_name'];
    $streamTitle = $json_array['stream']['channel']['status'];
    $currentGame = $json_array['stream']['channel']['game'];
 
    echo "$channelTitle is online playing $currentGame";
} else {
    echo "$channelName is offline";
}
?>
```

Comment: This code is syntactically correct. There must other code which is included...

Comment: Code works as in the demo here: http://runnable.com/U-jKKuB9A1YeDncC/php-demo

Comment: Works for me (though I get a notice about `$channelName` being undefined.

Comment: This code works without a problem. Make sure error is in this file and not in the file with the same name in other path.

Comment: print_r or var_dump the json array and check whether you are getting it right

Comment: Thank you guys for the fast answers :) I have no idea what is actually making this error tho, but probably my webserver is broken or something.

Answer (score 0):

This error happened to me just now, everything looked right until I realize that when I copied some line of code from Skype, it inserted some weird character acting like a space.

Check for weird invisible characters it might save your live.

Answer (score -2):

https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/superihippo
The above url is not sending anything in 'stream' keyword and you are accessing an array in it.

The response I got was

```
{
  "_links": {
    "self": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/superihippo",
    "channel": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/superihippo"
  },
   "stream": null
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes there is no syntax error. But you accessing an array which is not there.

Comment: if you run this url You will get the above response.

Comment: OP knows `stream` might be null that's why he uses `$json_array['stream'] != NULL` condition.

Comment: $json_array->stream use this. As it is returning an object.

Comment: @HarishLalwani it is not returning an object, OP is passing `true` as the second parameter to `json_decode`